# How to extract the essential word from elements of a list in Python

Tags: python

I have a list

```
ingredient = ['2 tablespoons butter',
 '1 1/2 cups long-grain rice',
 '1/2 cup chopped onion',
 '1/2 cup chopped green bell pepper',
 '1 clove garlic, minced']
```

I'd like to extract essential word from each element, to make the list to

```
['butter',
 'long-grain rice',
 'onion',
 'green bell pepper',
 'garlic']
```

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: How are you defining *"essential word"*? Also, what have you actually tried doing and what are you stuck on?

Comment: Well, I am thinking of getting rid of the all the numbers and count words. Say, I can make a special list of the numbers and count words, if any element in the list contains strings that match to the elements in the special list, the strings of that element should be removed.

Comment: Yes, you could do that. It's going to involve a bit of coding though (as do most things that have to do with string manipulation).

Comment: Great! can you give me a bit hint on this? I'd like to give a shot. Thank you very much!

Comment: Essentially all you have to do is iterate through your list (e.g.: `for s in ingredients:`) and then analyze each single string based on your criteria (personally I would use Python's [regex library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#), but other approaches can work as well). I'd recommend you try doing that, googling anything you are struggling with and only if you can't manage to solve one particular (sub-)problem post a question on SO

Answer (score 2):

To extract data from common sentences, you must create a dictionary( like a real dictionary(one we refer for meanings)) of words. In your case this dictionary must contain words related to quantities like `cup`, `cups`, `gram`, `grams` and words which mean past-tense of an action like `chopped`, `minced`, etc.

Now iterate over the first list.
Split each entry in list by space.
Remove following from the split list:

- Any numbers(int, double, float, etc)(you can parse `1/2` as numbers with `/` character in between them)
- Words that match your dictionary entries
- Any special characters( and terminal marks like comma, semicolon, etc)

Answer (score 2):

As noted in the comments, the definition of an "essential word" is up in the air. But if you want to keep a collection of "non-essential" words, the problem is straightforward. First, the data:

```
ingredients = ['2 tablespoons butter',
 '1 1/2 cups long-grain rice',
 '1/2 cup chopped onion',
 '1/2 cup chopped green bell pepper',
 '1 clove garlic, minced']

BAD_WORDS = {
    'chopped', 'cup', 'cups', 'clove', 'tablespoons', 'minced'
}
```

Then we create a couple of short helper functions to improve readability. The first takes a string and determines whether it contains a digit. We will use this to throw out words like `'1/2'`:

```
def contains_digit(w):
    return any(c.isdigit() for c in w)
```

The second is function that takes a word and determines whether it is generally bad. A word is bad if it shows up in `BAD_WORDS` or it contains a digit.

```
def is_bad(w):
    return (w in BAD_WORDS) or contains_digit(w)
```

Then we systematically remove the bad words:

```
extracted = []
for entry in ingredients:
    words = [w.strip(',') for w in entry.split()]
    remaining = [w for w in words if not is_bad(w)]
    extracted.append(' '.join(remaining))
```

The result is:

```
['butter', 'long-grain rice', 'onion', 'green bell pepper', 'garlic']
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I do realized that I need to create a list of 'essential words'.